# Find all values of parameter A such that two system of congruences are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm starting to learn some elementary number theory and i came across a task i don't know how to solve.

$$x \equiv 5 (mod \ 6)$$
$$x \equiv A (mod \ 35)$$

and the second one

$$x \equiv A (mod \ 10)$$
$$x \equiv 14(mod \ 21)$$

If i'm thinking in good way then we have to find such A's that we get same solution x for both systems. It reminds me about chinese remainder theory because 6 and 35 are relatively prime and 10 and 21 are too. 
But i have no idea how to use those facts to solve this problem.
I'd be really happy to know how to deal with such tasks. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Using CRT to reduce each system to equivalent systems mod primes we obtain

$\ \ x \equiv\ 1\pmod{2},\ x\equiv 2\pmod 3,\ x\equiv A\pmod 5,\ x\equiv \color{#c00}A\pmod 7\ $ is equivalent to the $1$st.
$\ \ x \equiv \color{#c00}A\pmod{2},\ x\equiv 2\pmod 3,\ x\equiv A\pmod 5,\ x\equiv\ 0\pmod 7\ $ is equivalent to the $2$nd.

Thus the two systems are equivalent $\iff \color{#c00}A \equiv\, \ldots$

Comment: If i'm thinking in right direction, only possible A's are that $2|A-1$ and $7|(x-A)$ and those two makes: 
A must be odd and A must be a multiply of 7, am i right?

Comment: @Chris The $2$nd should be $\, 7\mid 0 -A,\, $ so we reduce to solving $\, \color{#c00}A\equiv 1\pmod 2,\ \color{#c00}A\equiv 0\pmod 7  $